# Get buffer of line without joining itself in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a LineString which crosses itself (`LineString(...)`)
[image]

and make a Buffer out of it (`LineString().buffer(2, cap_style=BufferCapStyle.flat)`)

[image]

How to make the buffer not join itself and let it look like

[image]

?